# Closed-form solution in Euler's three-body problem and generalization of it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, three-body-problem

[Euler's three-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_three-body_problem) has a closed-form solution, but I cannot find it for it, but I've only found the equation for potential energy. What is the closed-form solution for the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of the moving mass given:

- The initial position of the moving mass.
- The initial velocity of the moving mass.
- The masses of the fixed masses and the moving mass.
- The distance between the fixed masses.

Can it be generalized to $N-1$ fixed masses? If so, what is the closed-form solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is given in the Wikipedia page you cite. For example it refers to generalisations up to five bodies,and gives a lot of detail about how the solution goes. You should ask a more focused question if there is anything you still don't understand when you have studied it.